# How can I setup multiple websites via Docker on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4

I have created a couple of C# .NET 5 websites and deployed them via Kestrel to my Raspberry Pi. I am using Docker and the setup I have is:
Website1 - uses port 5000 and port 5001 (https)
Website2 - uses port 5002 and port 5003 (https)

I configured port forwarding on my router with a range from 5000 to 5050. This must be setup correctly since Website1 is accessible from outside my network just fine and external IP works fine.

I can access Website2 from any machine on my local network (using raspberrypi:5002) but if I try to access from a device not connected to my network (using external IP address and port 5002) then it fails to load. I noticed this error on the Pi:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {b0a63215-b1e3-42f7-8d5b-921be6ed3d1a} was not found in the key ring.

It seems strange this error appears but I probably don't understand it to be honest as I normally just write code. Can anybody please advise what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

To preven this you need to automatically validate

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    });
  }
```

Cross-site request forgery (also known as XSRF or CSRF) is an attack against web-hosted apps whereby a malicious web app can influence the interaction between a client browser and a web app that trusts that browser. These attacks are possible because web browsers send some types of authentication tokens automatically with every request to a website. This form of exploit is also known as a one-click attack or session riding because the attack takes advantage of the user's previously authenticated session.

More info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0

https://andrewlock.net/automatically-validating-anti-forgery-tokens-in-asp-net-core-with-the-autovalidateantiforgerytokenattribute/

Optionally you can auto validate only for certain namespace -

options.TokenCookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);                options.AutoValidateIgnoredHttpMethods.Remove("GET");
options.AutoValidateFilter =type => !type.Namespace.StartsWith("App.Namespace.Name");

Comment: Thanks, so I tried your suggestions and also removed app.UseHttpsRedirection();  from the Startup.cs

Now I just receive the following error in the browser - This site can’t be reached.

Nothing appears on Putty which is connected to the Pi so at least the https message has gone.

For clarity:
http:raspberrypi:5002 - works
http:123.123.123.123:5002 - doesn't load

I have replaced my IP with 123 etc.

Comment: Ok, I have discovered that the website loads fine if I turn off the Wifi on my phone. My network seems to be 'blocking' the website somehow.